# Replacing all `&` but not the one in XML entity `&amp;` with `#` with sed in a given XML tag

Tags: sed, regular-expression, xml

I needed to replace all `&` with `#`, inside and only inside the `<faultstring> ... </faultstring>` tag. Additionally, the `&` in `&amp;` should not be changed. Sample input:

```
123&&<faultcode>IBM.Error<faultstring>special character & and one converted &amp;</faultstring></faultcode>&&123
```

Expected output:

```
123&&<faultcode>IBM.Error<faultstring>special character # and one converted &amp;</faultstring></faultcode>&&123
```

The following one works with the boundary but also replaces the `&amp;` with `#amp;`

```
sed -e :1 -e 's@\(<faultstring>.*\)&\(.*</faultstring>\)@\1#\2@;t1'
```

Also, I'm replacing those patterns inplace with a file.

PS: I created a new question to avoid confusion on [my previous thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152621/replace-specified-character-between-two-strings). If you guys found that this can be merged on the previous thread please do so. I'm just hoping that new thread will attract people to answer quick, and minimize confusion.

Comment: Your question title is confusing. From the body of your question, it looks like you mean “… replace a specified character between two words but only replace if the character ***doesn’t have*** a succeeding specified ***word***”. Also, what if `&` is used in other HTML characters, like `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&alpha;`, `&beta;`, etc?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's@\(<faultstring>.*\)&\([^amp;]\)\(.*</faultstring>\)@\1#\2\3@;t1' file
```

To replace it with `&amp;` use this:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's@\(<faultstring>.*\)&\([^amp;]\)\(.*</faultstring>\)@\1\&amp;\2\3@;t1' file
```

Comment: thanks @chaos! this worked fine! i tried to change the # to &amp; but it ddnt work. i tried to escape the ; with \; but no luck. how can i use &amp; instead of #?

Comment: oopps. nevermind. i already got it. i changed the \1# to \1\&amp thank you very much!

Comment: @kemaro see my edit

Comment: @kemaro oops, didnt see you 2nd comment...

Comment: hmm ok so first part is done. i would like to change the character that needs to replace? i cant make ' and " work. i like the following to converted.' to &apos;then " to & quot; then < to &lt; and > to & gt; can you help me @chaos?

Comment: update: i managed to make " < and > to work. but for ' to be converted to &apos; no luck.

Comment: lol after some experiments it worked. i changed all ' to " so that it will not see the ' as end of statement. now all is working :D