# Replacing a & in XML correctly?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to replace a '&' with `&amp;` 
Except the following occurance of XML special characters.

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

I tried the method mentioned in [Replace specified character between two strings?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152621/replace-specified-character-between-two-strings) and [Replacing all `&` but not the one in XML entity `&amp;` with `#` with sed in a given XML tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152725/replacing-all-but-not-the-one-in-xml-entity-amp-with-with-sed-in-a-g?lq=1) does not seem to work for me.

Comment: If you have perl use it with a negative lookahead regex. If you only want to use sed it gets more complicated.

Comment: never tried perl. If you have a soln, please let me know.

Comment: This feels like it might be an `XY Problem`. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/&(?!(quot|apos|lt|gt|amp);)/&amp;/g'
```

The `-p` flag makes perl behave like sed (loop over STDIN lines, do things, print to STDOUT), `-e` tells it to read the command from argument not file.

Regular expression substitution does this:

- match `&`

  - not followed by
  - `quot` or `apos` ... `amp`
  - semicolon
- replace with `&amp;`
- for all matches on line.

To use it like sed, e.g.

```
perl -pe 's/&(?!(quot|apos|lt|gt|amp);)/&amp;/g' < my-file.xml
./myscript.sh | perl -pe 's/&(?!(quot|apos|lt|gt|amp);)/&amp;/g'
```