# How to replace XML encodings like &amp;

Tags: text-processing, xml

I need to do exactly the opposite of [Replacing a & in XML correctly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263821/replacing-a-in-xml-correctly).

This is because I want to make human-readable some XML that I get from a log. Thus, I'd like to use
 `xmllint --format`,
but it complains about how "&","<", ">" and the like are encoded.

I am going to do this on MacOS and `perl` is available.

Comment: post a testable xml fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned perl, [XML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/~sixtease/XML-Entities-1.0002/lib/XML/Entities.pm) will do what you want. Example:

```
 use XML::Entities;
 $a = "Tom &amp; Jerry &copy; Warner Bros&period;";
 $b = XML::Entities::decode('all', $a);
```

$b Will be the string  "Tom & Jerry © Warner Bros."